# Blender 3D - Movie Frames around an arc

Tags: animation, path

I'd like to create an animation in which several movie segments are playing in separate plane objects that follow one another around an arc within the camera view. I can get a single movie playing on a plane object but I'm not sure how to get the plane to not only move along the arc but also rotate so that the plane faces the camera through out the movement. I will be having the objects moving only through a 1/4 circle.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you wanting the plane objects to follow a path? Am I understanding you correctly?

Answer (score 1):

An object can be animated along a path by *[Follow path Constrained](https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/constraints/relationship/follow_path.html)* to set its orientation toward the camera you need also a *[Track To Constrained](https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/constraints/tracking/track_to.html)*

[image]

The duration of the animation can be controlled in the curves settings:

[image]

[image]