# Trail particles ending in a point?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

I'm back with another question.

I've been working on a particle system, and I have a cube which outputs square particles from its volume without a normal movement value, then, I move the cube around (via keyframing).

My only problem is that particles usually achieve something similar to the right side of this image:

[image: Rays]

When what I really want to achieve is what's on the left.

Is there any way I could move the particles to form a point at the end?

Comment: Help anyone? :/

Comment: Could you upload the .blend here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ?

Comment: Hey, it's not that hard to just set up a cube that emits particles from its volume. I'm not uploading 5MB of something anyone can do. Besides, that's all my project is, a cube that emits cube particles from its volume.

Comment: I tried this hours ago but couldn't find out how you setup the materials to fade out (particle node/lifetime) whether or not you emit objects (since cycles doesn't support halos) and so on. The basic scene with an animated cube shouldn't take 5mb.

Comment: xD the above image is not a render, just an example :)

Comment: Still, I'm interested to see how you'd curve the particles.

Comment: Just add a follow path constrained as described here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44459/blender-3d-movie-frames-around-an-arc/44473#44473

Comment: I'll try that and see how it goes.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not completely sure how to do this... could you post an 'answer' with more information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could emit objects from a vertex group of a ico sphere. Let the emitter follow a curve a force field could follow the emitter and attract all particles. The distance of the force field can be controlled by offset.

[image]

The fade out of the trail can be controlled by the particles age e.g.

[image]

(Note that the particle count has been lowered in the .blend) The age is not correctly calculated when using child particles.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that you need to apply Size-over-Age texture to your particle system.

Size is, apparently, the key influence, the velocity -- optional.[image]

Comment: I'm not trying to make it smaller as it ages, I'm trying to curve it specifically.

Comment: @Flaeon sorry I got your pictures wrong -- both of them kind of curved to me. If you don't want to reduce the size of the particles, just add physical forces to your scene to influence (curve) particles trajectories. You can control the influence to the specific type of force in the particle system config.