# How to get this type of light streak in blender render (In Animated Format not Rendered)

Tags: animation

[image]

I've looked through the blender tutorials on YouTube and others, but I cannot find the correct one for this effect. How can I make that kind of light streak as in the picture (behind Sonic The Hedgehog)

Comment: You want it for a still render or you want to animate it?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24251/how-to-create-motion-trail-in-cycles or: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45328/trail-particles-ending-in-a-point/45476#45476

Comment: In Animated format please.

Comment: would this answer be useful? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/94976