# Create a trail effect (Meteor, Comet)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, volumetrics, motion-blur

I am trying to show a sphere with a trail, like the one shown in the image. I have tried using keyframes and moving the object from one point to another, and then enabling motion blur. This is not giving the desired effect. Any advice on how to achieve enter image description here this effect?

[image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117090/particles-with-motion-trails   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45328/trail-particles-ending-in-a-point   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112746/atmospheric-trail

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With current experimental build 2.91 you can base this on **Volume Object**.

- create the shape from a *Mesh Object*.
- add *Volume Object* and in modifiers choose **Mesh to Volume**, as source *Object* choose created shape one
- add *Point Light* object in trail direction (close to a sphere)

[image]

[image]

[image]

With second modifier **Volume Displace** you can use texture to distort. Here is a few examples of *Cloud* texture (variations in texture properties level).

[image]

[image]

Since I don't see an option to animate Texture position (for now) for *Volume Displace* modifier, here is a basic node material ...

[image]

[image]

[image]

With additional Curve modifier (for mesh Trail) or Wiggle bones you would be able to animate motion in more natural way (like a flame moved from one place to another).

Comment: That's great to hear about those new features for volumes - I really like the prospect of volume displacement - and a really good way of using them to get the effect. Some really exciting features coming in 2.91.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with particles:

[image]

Create your meteor, give it a particle system, in the *Field Weights* switch off the *Gravity*, in the *Velocity* give a bit of *Normal* and *Object Aligned X* to give the particles a direction. Create a stretched sphere that will be your particle, in the particle system *Render* panel choose *Render As > Object* and under *Object > Instance Object* choose the sphere. Set the other values like the life length of the particles, etc... Then give the particle the following material so that the particles fade out:

[image]

Add a *Force Field > Turbulence* just behind the meteor, and a *Force Field > Force* with a negative value a bit further, so that the particles are a bit agitated and then converge to the same point. Create a long mesh that contains the meteor and its tail in order to add a kind of smoke around the meteor and behind:

[image]