# Does anyone know how to make an atmospheric re-entry smoke that looks like air trail?

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation

I want to make an atmospheric reentry scene but I don't know how to make smoke looks like trail :

[image]

This image comes from this video (21:50)  :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XsuLEjWlp0E

I tried many smoke simulations but i'm not sure if mantaflow is capable of that, does anyone have an idea how to de it?

Thank you

Comment: This seems to me a bit much to fit into a single answer. Simulation has a lot of stuff going on... I think you should just watch a few tutorials and learn to use it. As far as capability of Mantaflow goes I am not really sure where these doubts come from. Of course you can achieve results like that with Mantaflow. It is designed precisely for this.

Comment: You have a similar question here, check the first answer and just change the material: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199172/create-a-trail-effect-meteor-comet