Fire simulation casts light with weird holes/shadows in it. How can I fix this?
This project uses a shadow catcher to catch light and shadows and is composited onto my footage. I'm using adaptive domain (though I tried a low res bake with no adaptive domain, that just killed any light I was getting before), with the domain set to not cast shadows in Object Properties > Ray Visibility.
I'll include some of the stills from the animation so far, but the gist of the matter is this: My fire casts a nice, warm, roundish light and it looks great from the first two frames of fire. On the third frame, it's almost as if an invisible cube is casting a shadow between the fire and the shadow catcher I have for the ground. Fourth frame is similar, but with a bigger, sort of pixel-y circle, and beyond frame four there's no light being cast.
Frame 1

Frame 2

Frame 3

Frame 4

The only objects in my scene are:
Camera
Shadow catcher plane
Domain
Flame inflow 1
Flame inflow 2
Flame inflow 3
Each inflow is marked as invisible to renders, plus they're icospheres anyway, so I don't think it's them casting shadows from inside the fire.
Not sure it matters, but I'm using two render layers, one with just the fire, and the second with just the shadow catcher; indirect bounces turned on for the fire and camera on layer two.
Any help would be appreciated!
I may have messed up the photo formatting, I've never posted here before, sorry in advance.
Edit -
Maybe it has something to do with how voxel-y the fire looks? It's at 850 resolution divisions, but maybe I just need more? Here's another pic


Anyone know what could be causing this?

Domain lowres ... number of divisions is related to longest edge of your domain ... there is nothing easier to confirm that than just encrease it. If your domain covers start end position of sphere inflow it would be always hard to calculate sim. Consider animate domain location covering just a sphere and fire tail. Or consider this approache https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/199176/2214

or multiple domains ... https://vimeo.com/246353861

So low res divisions contributes to the lighting problem? That seems really weird, but I'll take a stab at using multiple domains. Thanks!

Rather start with one domain with animated location ... Multiple can be tricky.

Yes, I noticed this yesterday... I'll try animating, thanks!
